# Bug with IOS fullscreen html5 video

Tags: javascript, ios, css

2 day I suffer from a problem. There is a project - a video quest. The video is played in full-screen mode and buttons appear on it at the right time. On macOS, Android, win everything is fine, and IOS does not allow to display content on top of the video, so it adds its own controls, which should not be. How can this be fixed?

This is HTML.

```
<video id="myVideo"  preload="metadata" src='https://embed-ssl.wistia.com/deliveries/7fad081767e9c9bd736c36e556c33fbf54b9d2e0/quest.mov'>
                        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
                    </video>
<div class="selected_btns">
  <div id="section1" class="section_list">
      <div class="button"> 
          <a href="#" data-place="21" data-end='30' onclick="trackOutboundLink('rise_of_machines','first_stop'); return false;">Это восстание машин и надо спасаться!»</a>
     </div>
     <div class="button">          
          <a href="#" data-place="32" data-end='41' onclick="trackOutboundLink('future_here','first_stop'); return false;">Вау, будущее уже здесь, давай познакомимся!</a>
    </div>   

    <div class="progress_bar">
        <div class="bee_progress">
                <div class="bee_bar" id='bar_1'>0</div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I use native js, jquery, w/o other frameworks.

Get fullscreen

```
function requestFullscreen( element ) {
    if ( element.requestFullscreen ) {
      element.requestFullscreen();
    } else if ( element.mozRequestFullScreen ) {
      element.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if ( element.webkitRequestFullScreen ) {
      element.webkitRequestFullScreen( Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT );
    //   element.webkitRequestFullScreen();

    }
```

And have 2 problems ONLY on ios.

1) In fullscreen mode show system video controls

2) I cant set block with buttons on video.

On Adnroid all work right.

Comment: show the code, and which framework?

Comment: edit question ..